# Loopback where filter not working inside include

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

I have this filter written that i am passing to my endpoint written in Loopbackjs.

```
  const filter = {
            where: { status: { neq: "processed" } },
            include: [
                { relation: "vendor", scope: { fields: ["id", "name"] } },
                {
                    relation: "pickupLocation",
                    scope: { where: { cityId: "5ee134da0138634c27a6e1dd" } },
                },
            ],
            limit: 200,
            skip: 0
        };
        return this.http.get<IPickupRequest[]>(
            `${environment.url}/PickupRequests?filter=${encodeURIComponent(
                JSON.stringify(filter)
            )}`
        );
```

The `pickupRequest` collection contains a `belongsTo` relation to pickupLocation collection. The pickupLocation collection contains a property called `cityId` on which i am trying to apply a where clause but it does not work. Moreover I also want to get the fields of pickupLocation too inside the pickupRequest object so that i cna use them in my table. The simple include works perfectly and shows the data as desired but when `where` clause is applied it just doesn't work and also shows only pickupRequest object but does not include pickupLocation data inside it. Moreover since i am using pagination I need it to return me exactly 200 records each time. Am i doing something wrong? What is the exact issue here? I am using Loopback 3

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are expecting that `where` filter applied on the `pickupLocation` relation would act something similar to SQL's inner join. However, in loopback, whenever you do an `include` in the query, the framework internally makes two separate queries on collections or tables of each of those models and combine them; effectively making it work like SQL's left outer join. So, in the above query `PickupRequest` list will have all object, irrespective of where filter on `pickupLocation` model. The `pickupLocation` relation would be present only in those `PickupRequest` records where `cityId = "5ee134da0138634c27a6e1dd"` and remaining places, the relation would be an `null` object.

To overcome this problem, I would say, make your primary query on `pickupLocation` model as per the `{ cityId: "5ee134da0138634c27a6e1dd" }` where filter and do an include  of `PickupRequest` model.